# Netgear won't block Xbox Live

Tags: router

I want to kick someone off my wireless. They're using the Xbox. I can't use the xbox in anyway way. I only have access to my router.

First, I tried blocking all the ports xbox live uses. That didn't work, so I looked through the connected devices and thought I saw it (I recognised all but two computers, both of their names were `<unknown>`)

So I tried selectively blocking them and that didn't work. So I tried block *all* connected devices, like this:

[image]

This blocks access for anything *but* the xbox. My router is a Netgear WNDR4300. How do I block access?

I want to have the person *want* (or at least feel the need) to get off it. I therefore can't let them know I'm doing anything, so everything I do has to be done from another (windows 8) computer on the same network. It is my xbox though and it's signed into my xbox live account.

Comment: Hmmm...I would simply enable MAC addess filtering on your router. Next time you have an opportunity, obtain the MAC address of your XBox 360. IIRC, the XBox 360 somehow uses the same MAC address for both wired and wireless connections. So, just find the wired MAC address: https://www.dhnet.ufl.edu/getconnected/tutorials/xbox/.

After you do that, enter that MAC address in your MAC address filter. A MAC address filter can actually work two ways. You can allow only the MAC addresses in your filter list to be connected to your router, or you can have your router prohibit MAC addresses.

Comment: I put `Netgear WNDR4300` in the body, do you mean something else?

Comment: Why don't you log in to your Xbox live account and change the password. See https://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/change-microsoft-account-password .